# Matplotlib could not generate an accurate slider plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following equation:

[image: img]

```
y = ((b-6(x**k))/c)**(1/k)
k = 10/(6+c)
```

I know that when k > 1 then y is concave and when 0 < k < 1 then y is convex. However, the problem is that in the generated plot it does not matter whatever the value of k is, it always generates a concave y. I was wondering if anybody can help me to figure out what is the problem.

Codes to generate the dynamic plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
x = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
b_init = 1
c_init = 0
k = 10/(6+c_init)
delta_f = 1.0
y = ((b_init-6*(x**k))/c_init)**(1/k)
l, = plt.plot(x, y, lw=2)
ax.margins(x=0)

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
ax_b = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
ax_c = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

s_b = Slider(ax_b, 'b', 0.1, 18.0, valinit=b_init, valstep=delta_f)
s_c = Slider(ax_c, 'c', 0.1, 12.0, valinit=c_init)


def update(val):
    b = s_b.val
    c = s_c.val
    l.set_ydata(((b-6*(x**k))/c)**(1/k))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


s_b.on_changed(update)
s_c.on_changed(update)

resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')


def reset(event):
    s_b.reset()
    s_c.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

def colorfunc(label):
    l.set_color(label)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are working with juypter notebooks you can use the widgets from `ipywidgets` as shown below.
Also, to get an intuition, it might help if you print out the b,c and k values.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
from ipywidgets import *

def y(x,b,c):
    k = 10/(6+c)
    print(f' b={b:.3f},c={c:.3f},k={k:.3f}')
    y = ((b-6*(x**k))/c)**(1/k)
    return y

def inter(b0,c0):
    y1=y(x,b0,c0)
    p.figure(figsize=(20,6))
    p.plot(x,y1)

dx=0.001    
x = np.arange(0, 1.0+dx, dx)  #  assuming you want to go to 1 inclusively

b0=widgets.FloatSlider(value=10,min=-1,max=18.0,step=0.01, 
                       description='b0', 
                       continuous_update=False,
                       readout_format='.3f',
                       layout=Layout(width='90%', height='20px'))

c0=widgets.FloatSlider(value=0.1,min=-1,max=12.0,step=0.01, 
                       description='c0', 
                       continuous_update=False,
                       readout_format='.3f',
                       layout=Layout(width='90%', height='20px'))

interact(inter, b0=b0,c0=c0);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @roadrunner66 for the answer. Could you please let me know what is wrong with my codes? In addition, if I want x and y both be between 0 and 1, how can I add this assumption into your codes?

Comment: You just change these values `value=0.1,min=-1,max=12.0,step=0.01, ` to anything you like. `value` has to be between `min` and `max`. In your case `c_init` was outside of the interval spanned by `0.1` and `12`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another problem which is when I change the value of b0 to values less than 6 an error comes up which says: 
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  if __name__ == '__main__':
Do you have any idea how can I fix this problem?

Comment: When 6*x**k is larger than b, you try to take a root of a negative number for many cases of k.